# Django template debugging and un-suppressing exceptions

Tags: python, django, debugging, django-templates

As an example, I just had this bug:

```
{% for object in some_list %}
<li{% if object.time.date > read_time %}class="unread"{% endif %}>
    {{ object }}
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

This was failing silently because I was comparing a `datetime.date` with a `datetime.datetime`. I found the problem by creating a custom filter, passing both variables in and printing their respective `__repr__`. A big waste of time. I could also have used [django-template-debug](https://github.com/calebsmith/django-template-debug), but that is still quite indirect.

How can I get access to the exception that would have been thrown internally at the comparison? More generally, how can I get more exceptions from django templates?

Both `DEBUG` and `TEMPLATE_DEBUG` are True. I have the [debug_toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) which is quite useful, but not in this case. I've tried playing with `TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID` but that seems to have no affect at all.

Comment: Partially off topic but PyCharm Pro lets you debug your django templates. On-topic - I would imagine there would be handling within the template code of django for this, as to exactly where I don't know but you would be able to set breakpoints here